# Logstash pipeline pushing the data without transforming it to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I'm using a docker-compose file with the ELK stack (Elastic, Logstash, Kibana). The `docker-compose.yml` file is very straight forward:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services: 
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.2
    ports:
      - 9300:9300
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - http.cors.allow-methods=OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
      - http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
      - transport.host=127.0.0.1
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - share-network
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.2
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - share-network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  logstash:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .local.env
    volumes: 
      - ./pipelines/provider_scores.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
      - 5044:5044
    networks:
      - share-network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
volumes:
  elasticsearch_data:
networks:
  share-network:
```

The `Dockerfile` in the Logstash service is just to install a few plugins to the Logstash image from Docker:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.3.2

# install dependency
RUN /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
RUN /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-aggregate
RUN /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-jdbc_streaming
RUN /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-mutate

# copy lib database jdbc jars
COPY ./drivers/mysql/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mysql-connector-java.jar
COPY ./drivers/sql-server/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre11.jar /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mssql-jdbc.jar
COPY ./drivers/oracle/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/ojdbc6.jar
COPY ./drivers/postgres/postgresql-42.2.8.jar /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/postgresql.jar
```

And the provider_scores.conf file looks like this:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_DRIVER_JAR_LOCATION}"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://${DbServer};database=${DataDbName}"
        jdbc_user => "${DataUserName}"
        jdbc_password => "${DataPassword}"
        schedule => "${CronSchedule_Metrics}"
        statement => "
            select pws.ProviderID,
                pws.SpeedScore,
                pws.QualityScore
            from ProviderWeightedOverallScore pws
            order by pws.ProviderID
            "
    }
}
filter {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{ProviderID}"
        code => "
             map['providerid'] ||= event.get('ProviderID')
             map['kpi'] ||= []
             map['kpi'] << {
                'speedscore' => event.get('SpeedScore'),
                'qualityscore' => event.get('QualityScore')
                }
             event.cancel()
        "      
        push_previous_map_as_event => true
        timeout => 3
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"]
        document_id => "%{providerid}"
        index => "testing-%{+YYYY.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss}"
        action => "update"
        doc_as_upsert => true
    }
    stdout {  }

}
```

That's my docker configuration. Everything runs ok, the only issue is that the `filter->aggregate` part is not working, the Elastic Index is being filled with straight data, no transformation occurred.

Any clue why the filter section is not transforming the data?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this is that Logstash pipelines are handled by multiple worker threads depending on the number of CPUs you have. By default, the [`pipeline.workers` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.3/logstash-settings-file.html) is set to the number of CPUs you have available on your host.

In order to work correctly, the `aggregate` filter [must run with a single worker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.3/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-description) otherwise events might not all go through the same worker thread.

So you should make sure to set `pipeline.workers: 1` or make sure you have the [environment variable `PIPELINE_WORKERS`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.3/docker-config.html#docker-env-config) set to 1

Comment: I am having the same issue. I tried using the example given here.  And my aggregate doesn't seem to work even after setting pipeline.workers to 1.  I get all  data at the same level without getting nested under KPI. Can you please help ?

Comment: @user2506233 please create a new thread with your config

Comment: I had to make field name in task_id to all lowercase. And ofcourse as you mentioned I had to set pipeline.workers to 1. Thanks for the help to solve this @Val.